# Unable to change from DHCP to Static

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

New Ubuntu 17.10.1 install.
Network is up and running on DHCP, trying to change it to static and point to local DNS server.
ran `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and it only shows the loopback interface.  I added the following, saved, reboot the server, it still using DHCP.

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.10
```

What am I missing?